# Convert C++ method to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have a method that decrypts a base64 and I need to convert it to c#, I've tried to use the Convert.FromBase64String of C# and some other tips I've looked here, but the final string doesn't match the result on c++.

Can someone give a hand to understand this peace of code of c++?

Example input: `lWXtYpNpwBBXoLmcuktDqg==`

Expected output: `AC0105E92ED496ACD373D7496B76C1C8`

Output using Convert.FromBase64: `95-65-ED-62-93-69-C0-10-57-A0-B9-9C-BA-4B-43-AA`

```
static BYTE BackFrom64[]={
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0x3e,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x3f,
0x34,0x35,0x36,0x37,0x38,0x39,0x3a,0x3b,
0x3c,0x3d,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,
0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0a,0x0b,0x0c,0x0d,0x0e,
0x0f,0x10,0x11,0x12,0x13,0x14,0x15,0x16,
0x17,0x18,0x19,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0x1a,0x1b,0x1c,0x1d,0x1e,0x1f,0x20,
0x21,0x22,0x23,0x24,0x25,0x26,0x27,0x28,
0x29,0x2a,0x2b,0x2c,0x2d,0x2e,0x2f,0x30,
0x31,0x32,0x33,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff
```

};

```
static BYTE * TabBase64=(BYTE *)"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";


int FromBase64(BYTE *Output,BYTE *Input,int BufSize,int MaxSize) {

    int              xut,txut;
    int              i,t,k,shift;
    BYTE             c;
    dWORD            dr,dr1;

    xut=txut=t=0;
    dr=0L;
    for(i=0; i < BufSize; ++i) {
        c=*Input++;
        if(c == '=') {
            break;
        }
        if((c=BackFrom64[c]) == 0xff) {
            continue;
        }
        dr1=(dWORD)c;
        shift=(32-(6*(t+1)));
        dr1<<=shift;
        dr|=dr1;
        t++;
        if(t == 4) {
            t=0;
            for(k=0; k < 3; ++k) {
                dr1=dr;
                dr1>>=(32-(8*(k+1)));
                dr1&=0xff;
                *Output++=(BYTE) dr1;
                if(++txut >= MaxSize) {
                    return(-1);
                }
            }
            dr=0;
        }
    }
    if(t > 0) {
        for(k=0; k < (t-1); ++k) {
            dr1=dr;
            dr1>>=(32-(8*(k+1)));
            dr1&=0xff;
            *Output++=(BYTE) dr1;
            if(++txut >= MaxSize) {
                return(-1);
            }
        }
    }
    return(txut);
}
```

Comment: What's the input, actual output and what's the expected output?

Comment: If you replace pointer arithmetic with plain index array access then code should compile as-is. That said...if C++ implementation output differs then I'd seriously consider it as buggy (even without inspecting your code then I might be wrong). BTW you're not _decrypting_ but _decoding_.

Comment: What is `BackFrom64`?

Comment: Why not use standard library methods : Convert.FromBase64String Convert.ToBase64String

Comment: @jdweng. Because it produces different output. OP said that: "the final string doesn't match the result on c++"

Comment: Can you provide some inputs and its corresponding expected output?

Comment: The naive approach would be to write it like this in C#: Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString); Sorry, didn't see that was already in the question :-)

Comment: Just added the Input and the expected output.

Comment: I don't get your expected output from your code, I get the same as C#: https://www.ideone.com/C6L8Fb That's assuming that BackFrom64 is constructed from TabBase64 in the obvious way. If it's not, i.e. the characters are not mapped in the standard way, then you'll have to show us BackFrom64.

Comment: Thanks. Here's the version with your BackFrom64: https://www.ideone.com/a40JAe And it's the same result - matches C#, doesn't match your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

A very naive conversion with minimal work follows.

- the types have been changed to C# types
- the pointer increments have been changed to indexes into arrays

The only other change was to calculate the unsupplied `BackFrom64` array as the inverse of the `TabBase64` array, and to add a unit test for the supplied input and output.  If it did something other than the standard algorithm, then I'd tidy up the counters, some of which are redundant (probably both `i` and `iInput` could be replaced with `foreach(var c in input)`

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace SO
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private const string TabBase64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
        private static readonly byte[] BackFrom64 = CreateBackFrom64();

        private static byte[] CreateBackFrom64()
        {
            var backFrom64 = new byte[128];

            for (var i = 0; i < backFrom64.Length; ++i)
                backFrom64[i] = 0xff;

            for (byte i = 0; i < TabBase64.Length; i++)
            {
                var c = TabBase64[i];
                backFrom64[c] = i;
            }

            return backFrom64;
        }

        int FromBase64(byte[] Output, string Input, int BufSize, int MaxSize)
        {
            int xut, txut;
            int i, t, k, shift;
            byte c;
            int dr, dr1;

            xut = txut = t = 0;
            dr = 0;

            var iInput = 0;
            var iOutput = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < BufSize; ++i)
            {
                c = (byte)Input[iInput++];
                if (c == '=')
                {
                    break;
                }
                if ((c = BackFrom64[c]) == 0xff)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                dr1 = c;
                shift = (32 - (6 * (t + 1)));
                dr1 <<= shift;
                dr |= dr1;
                t++;
                if (t == 4)
                {
                    t = 0;
                    for (k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
                    {
                        dr1 = dr;
                        dr1 >>= (32 - (8 * (k + 1)));
                        dr1 &= 0xff;
                        Output[iOutput++] = (byte)dr1;
                        if (++txut >= MaxSize)
                        {
                            return (-1);
                        }
                    }
                    dr = 0;
                }
            }
            if (t > 0)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < (t - 1); ++k)
                {
                    dr1 = dr;
                    dr1 >>= (32 - (8 * (k + 1)));
                    dr1 &= 0xff;
                    Output[iOutput++] = (byte)dr1;
                    if (++txut >= MaxSize)
                    {
                        return (-1);
                    }
                }
            }
            return (txut);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var input = @"lWXtYpNpwBBXoLmcuktDqg==";
            var expectedOutput = "AC0105E92ED496ACD373D7496B76C1C8";

            var converted = new byte[(input.Length * 2) / 3];

            var result = FromBase64(converted, input, input.Length, int.MaxValue);

            Assert.AreNotEqual(-1, result, "result is valid");

            Assert.AreEqual(
                BitConverter.ToString(converted).Replace("-",""),
                BitConverter.ToString(Convert.FromBase64String(input)).Replace("-",""),
                "Supplied algorithm matches standard algorithm" );

            Assert.AreEqual(
                expectedOutput,
                BitConverter.ToString(converted).Replace("-",""),
                "Supplied algorithm matches expected output" );
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the first assert passes because the ported code returns exactly the same result as `Convert.FromBase64String` but the second one fails as this not the output you say you get from the C++.

From this I would conclude that the most likely cause of the difference is when the C++ version is being called, the content of `BackFrom64` has not been initialised correctly and contains junk values - the values for `BackFrom64` supplied in edit to OP result in the same output as the calculated ones, so something else is going on with the expected result. Compiling the C++ version and running with the given input:

```
int main()
{
    const char* input = "lWXtYpNpwBBXoLmcuktDqg==";

    BYTE Input[100];
    BYTE Output[100];

    int length = strlen(input);

    memcpy(Input, input, length);

    int result = FromBase64(Output, Input, 100, length);

    for (int i = 0; i < result; ++i)
        std::cout << std::hex << (int)Output[i] << " ";

    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Generates the output

```
95 65 ed 62 93 69 c0 10 57 a0 b9 9c ba 4b 43 aa
```

which again indicates that it's the same as the standard algorithm.